# jquery templates - Templating a HTML page

Tags: jquery, templates

I'm writing a tool to generate HTML pages using jquery templates, but it does not like certain tags (DOCTYPE, html, head). Is it possible to template something like this:

```
<script id="HtmlPageTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
       <title>${PageTitle}</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
       <script src="scripts/script.js">{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
       <script>
           function MyFunction(){
           }
       {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{tmpl "#PageBody"}}
    </body>
    </html>
</script>
```

I'm using {{html "< /sc"+"ript>"}} to close script tags without closing the template script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be useful for you :

The basic idea is - replace '<' of all sensitive tag with some special mark, e.g., '@#'
and replace @# to '<'. Use $.template() to compile the template. Finally, render.

```
<script id="HtmlPageTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
       <title>${PageTitle}</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
       @#script src="scripts/script.js">@#/script>
       @#script>
                alert('here');
       @#/script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{tmpl "#PageBody"}}
    </body>
    </html>
</script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And replace the template using

```
$.template('test', $('#HtmlPageTemplate').html().split('@#').join('<'));
$.tmpl('test', data).appendTo($("#output"));
```

Comment: at least... this is a easier hack.. LOL